# How we know current location of user in asp.net mvc 4 using google map?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, google-maps

I want to know the current location of user in asp.net MVC 4, because my client want to see the last five login location of any particular user on map means I have two problem first is know and save the user current location and second is display last five location on google map of that user. I want to use only google service, not any other third party tools or service.

Comment: Could you post your code what you have tried so far.

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow. Please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example of your code and the problem you are facing.

Comment: i am very new for google map, I have no idea from where to start.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do this is in a way that gracefully falls back to the least accurate method.

First I would ask the user in the client for their location information in Javascript.

```
function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
             position.coords.latitude;
             position.coords.longitude;

             // You can use this in the client 
             // or send it to the server using AJAX.
        });
    } else {
        // Geolocation is not supported by this browser.
        // This is when you will have to use the IP address.
    }
}
```

If you can't get the location from the browser and then send this (possibly with an AJAX call) to the server, then use the IP address.

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress
```

The IP address is going to be less useful than just asking the user in the client as they might be using a proxy or VPN etc.

Comment: Sir, Ip can not give 100% correct user location . Please check it by below link. I am using this in my project. First click on the below link it give you your latitude and longitude, after this type "my location" on google map then you get different latitude and longitude, but you find google give 100% correct location.[link] (https://www.ipinfodb.com/index.php)